# Custom system call plus function gives wrong answer

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, virtualbox, system-calls

I am trying to create a custom system call in Ubuntu in Virtual Box. Here is the driver program which returns a very large negative number instead of the answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
long plus (int, int);
int main (int agrc, char* argv[]){
int arg1=atoi(argv[1]);
int arg2=atoi(argv[2]);
long x= syscall(436, (long)arg1, (long)arg2);
printf ("Sum: %ld\n", x);
return x;
}
```

The definition of plus.c system call:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
asmlinkage long sys_plus(long a, long b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Makefile for plus.c

```
obj-y := plus.o
```

The Makefile changed line in the main linux-5.3.7 directory:

```
core-y          += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ plus/
```

The syscall_64.tbl entry:

```
436       64        plus          sys_plus
```

The syscalls.h entry:

```
asmlinkage long sys_plus (long, long);
```

After this I am compiling the kernel with time make -j4 and the sudo make install. It appears I am doing everything fine yet the final output is wrong. What could be the issue?

Comment: Curious: Why use `atoi()` in `int arg1=atoi(argv[1]); ... (long)arg1` and not `long arg1=atol(argv[1]); ... arg1`?

Comment: Function declared `long plus (int, int);`, yet defined as `long plus (long, long) { ...`.  Is that intended?

Comment: Changing these things still produce the same result, a very large negative number.

Comment: You may wish to print the values passed to `sys_plus` in the driver with `printk` to verify that they have the values you intend.

Comment: Also, the `printk` will prove that `sys_plus` was called at all.

Comment: @Labeeb How to you change code to address `long plus (int, int);` [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71988928/custom-system-call-plus-function-gives-wrong-answer?noredirect=1#comment127204857_71988928)?

Comment: I just replace the int with long. Do you think that the error is in my driver program?

Comment: The return value from a syscall is a status value.